# pandas mask indexing misshaped DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Is there a built in way with pandas to accomplish this.

I'd prefer to avoid `pd.concat([...],1)` `.all(1)` methods as the dataset I'm working with has missing data points.

### main.py

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt

def _index_mask(index_a: pd.Index, index_b: pd.Index) -> npt.NDArray[np.bool_]:

    return index_b.isin(index_a[index_a.isin(index_b)])


def mask_b(a: pd.DataFrame, b: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return b[_index_mask(a.index, b.index)]


if __name__ == '__main__':

    frame_a = pd.DataFrame(
        np.arange(10).reshape(5, 2),
        index=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
    )
    frame_b = pd.DataFrame(
        np.arange(16).reshape(8, 2),
        index=["F", "G", "H", "C", "D", "E",  "I", "J"]
    )
    x = mask_b(frame_a, frame_b)
    print(x)
```

### edit

I forgot to mention that I also need to perform the inverse operation on `frame_a`

```
def _index_mask(index_a: pd.Index, index_b: pd.Index) -> tuple[npt.NDArray[np.bool_],npt.NDArray[np.bool_]]:


    return index_a.isin(index_b), index_b.isin(index_a)


mask_a, mask_b = _index_mask(frame_a.index, frame_b.index)
frame_a = frame_a[mask_a]
frame_b = frame_b[mask_b]
assert all(frame_b.index == frame_a.index)
```

### result

```
    0   1
C   6   7
D   8   9
E  10  11
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: not a problem I suppose. I guess I was just wondering if there was a more built in method for accomplishing this.

Comment: Okay, that's fine. I wasn't sure if that were the case or if you didn't finish the post :)

Comment: are you looking for `frame_b[frame_b.index.isin(frame_a.index)]`? basically what you already have there... then again, your title suggests something different...

Comment: yeah, I failed to demonstrate that I also need to normalize `frame_a`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`pd.Index.intersection`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
x = frame_b.loc[frame_a.index.intersection(frame_b.index)]
```

Output:

```
>>> x
    0   1
C   6   7
D   8   9
E  10  11
```